# Как сделать менеджер контактов с возможностью редактирования из админки?

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap, cms, wordpress-плагины

Приветствую, как можно реализовать менеджер контактов компании? Контакты должны группироваться по отделам компании, каждый отдел разбивается на руководство и сотрудников, у каждого контакта отображается фото, должность и т.д.
Была мысль реализовать на Bootstrap и посадить на Wordpress, но непонятно как сделать, чтобы через wordpress  выводились контакты и можно было через админку выводить. В гугле информации почти нет.

Есть ли какие-нибудь плагины для Wordpress или cms, которые более-менее подходят под такие задачи? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Есть, и немало. Например,

[Ultimate Member](https://ultimatemember.com/)

[BuddyPress](https://ru.buddypress.org/)